# Look for multiple strings in multiple columns for a particular item and return the colnames in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, grepl

I want to find two strings in multiple columns for a particular item. I need to get the colnames which contain "0/1" or "1/1" for each item in Item_Name.

Example dataframe:

| Item_Name | Sample_A | Sample_B | Sample_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nino1 | 0/1 | 0/0 | 1/1 |
| Nino2 | 0/0 | 1/1 | 0/1 |
| Nino3 | 1/1 | 0/1 | 0/0 |

**Expected Output:**

Nino1 - SampleA, Sample_C

Nino2 - Sample_B, Sample_C

Nino3 - Sample_A, Sample_B

Till now I know to use grepl to find one pattern at time. I am not sure how to get colnames part.

```
data_frame_mod  <- dataframe[Reduce(`|`, lapply(dataframe, grepl, pattern = "0/1"))]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly rudimentary way of doing it:

```
library(tidyverse)

desired <- c("0/1", "1/1")

dataframe |>
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(samples = names(dataframe)[c_across(everything()) %in% desired] |> paste(collapse = ", ")) |>
  ungroup()
```

Update: a one-liner:

```
mutate(df, goal = apply(df, 1, \(x) names(df)[x %in% desired] |> paste(collapse = ", ")))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Item_Name Sample_A Sample_B Sample_C samples           
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             
1 Nino1     0/1      0/0      1/1      Sample_A, Sample_C
2 Nino2     0/0      1/1      0/1      Sample_B, Sample_C
3 Nino3     1/1      0/1      0/0      Sample_A, Sample_B
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need reduce. Use `%in%`:

```
val <- as.matrix(df[-1]) %in% c('0/1', '1/1')
nms <- names(df[-1])[col(df[-1])][val]
transform(df, output = tapply(nms,row(df[-1])[val], toString))

 Item_Name Sample_A Sample_B Sample_C             output
1     Nino1      0/1      0/0      1/1 Sample_A, Sample_C
2     Nino2      0/0      1/1      0/1 Sample_B, Sample_C
3     Nino3      1/1      0/1      0/0 Sample_A, Sample_B
```

Notice that if you want to use grepl:

```
 grepl("[01]/1", as.matrix(df[-1]))
```

---

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Sample'),
                                ~ifelse(.x %in% c('0/1', '1/1'), cur_column(),NA),
                                .names = 'a_{col}')) %>%
    unite(output, starts_with('a'), sep = ', ', na.rm = TRUE)

  Item_Name Sample_A Sample_B Sample_C             output
1     Nino1      0/1      0/0      1/1 Sample_A, Sample_C
2     Nino2      0/0      1/1      0/1 Sample_B, Sample_C
3     Nino3      1/1      0/1      0/0 Sample_A, Sample_B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a very big frame, you can pivot and grep:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
quux |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -Item_Name) |>
  filter(value %in% c("0/1", "1/1")) |>
  summarize(res = toString(name), .by = Item_Name)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Item_Name res               
#   <chr>     <chr>             
# 1 Nino1     Sample_A, Sample_C
# 2 Nino2     Sample_B, Sample_C
# 3 Nino3     Sample_A, Sample_B
```

Or we can use `sapply` per group:

```r
quux |>
  summarize(
    res = toString(names(which(sapply(pick(starts_with("Sample_")), 
                                      `%in%`, c("0/1", "1/1"))))),
    .by = Item_Name)
#   Item_Name                res
# 1     Nino1 Sample_A, Sample_C
# 2     Nino2 Sample_B, Sample_C
# 3     Nino3 Sample_A, Sample_B
```

This latter one assumes one row per `Item_Name`.